# Calling MkdirAll with reference to root directory instead of working directory?

Tags: go, directory, filesystems, filepath, mkdir

I'm trying to build a service in go that writes to a file with reference to the root directory as opposed to the working directory.

For example, my working directory is `/Users/joe/dev/go` and I want to create a file `test.txt` in the directory `/Users/joe/generatedFiles/`. I want to write a file `/Users/joe/generatedFiles/test.txt`.

I can't write to this directory unless the folder `generatedFiles` is created else I get the error "no such file or directory."

To do this I plan on calling os.MkdirAll("Users/joe/generatedFiles/", os.ModePerm) but this isn't giving me the expected functionality. Instead, it creates the folder: `/Users/joe/dev/go/Users/joe/generatedFiles/`.

I've also tried calling `os.MkdirAll("/Users/joe/generatedFiles/", os.ModePerm)` with a slash at the beginning of the file path but this is doing nothing. What can I do to write to a file in reference to the root directory?

Comment: The absolute path (with the leading slash) is correct. If MkdirAll "does nothing" it either returns and error or the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) to specify the directory:

```
os.MkdirAll("/Users/joe/generatedFiles/", os.ModePerm)
```

Note the leading `/`.